# persisting layouts when page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have 2 buttons each one changes direction either ltr or rtl and i'm trying to make both views persist when they are clicked, if ltr is clicked the page stays on ltr layout even if refreshed until rtl is clicked and then rtl persists until there's a change
here's the code but it isn't working

```
             <button onclick ='changeToRTL()'>Right to Left</button>
             <button  onclick ='changeToLTR()'>Left to Right</button>
             


<script>
    function changeToLTR(){
  $('body').removeClass('direction-rtl').addClass('direction-ltr')
  window.onload=changeToLTR();
  // initiate();
}

function changeToRTL(){
  $('body').removeClass('direction-ltr').addClass('direction-rtl');
  window.onload=changeToRTL();

  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `localStorage` to store the chosen direction and load it on page load.

```js
function changeDirection( directionSuffix ) {
    // remove all classes starting with "direction"
  $('body').removeClass(function (index, css) {
     return (css.match (/\bdirection\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
  })
  // add the direction class
  .addClass('direction-' + directionSuffix);
  // set the local storage item
  localStorage.setItem('direction', directionSuffix);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // retrieve the localstorage item
  let storedDirection = localStorage.getItem('direction');
  // check if the item is set and if so call the "changeDirection" function
    if(typeof storedDirection !== 'undefined') {
    changeDirection( storedDirection );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick ='changeDirection("rtl")'>Right to Left</button>
<button  onclick ='changeDirection("ltr")'>Left to Right</button>
```